# Delphi XE2 : F12 switching between unit and form intolerably slow

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2

This one has been annoying me for a long time and having switched directly from D2007 to XE2 a few months back I can't vouch for when this may have started, but on D2007 I didn't have the issue.

The larger a unit grows, the slower it becomes to use F12 to switch between unit and form when code changes have been made. Even if you undock the form designer (back to D7 format), just clicking back into the form when code has been changed causes the BDS.exe to max out on CPU for a long time. In my case, on my largest form (30,000 lines) this can be over a minute. I'm not sure what checking is going on when reactivating the form, but if the IDE has been "told" that all is uptodate, then the switch is instantaneuos. My workaround is therefore to Ctrl+F9 to compile the form before reactivating the form. The time taken to compile is only a few seconds. I can then switch instantly to the form without issue. Compare that to the minute or more wait I endure if I don't compile before switching...

So, what are the possibilities, apart from reducing the unit size ?!

Comment: You should **really** consider reducing the unit size, if you have 30 k LOC units.

Comment: Perhaps Andreas Hausladen's IDE Fix Pack will help with this problem too (I don't know for sure), see http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack-2009-10/

Answer (score 8):

There is a bug in the LiveBindings design-time package that slows down the IDE. CodeCompletion (Ctrl+Space) and switching between form and code editor is very slow.
If you don't use LiveBindings or want to test if it is really the LiveBindings design-time code, you can disable the LiveBinding packages under *Component/Installed Packages...*. They are `Embarcadero LiveBindings Components`, `Embarcadero LiveBindings Components FireMonkey` and `Embarcadero LiveBindings Components VCL`. If you disable the first, the other 2 will automatically be unloaded.

In case you use LiveBindings in your project you have to either wait for an Update or you can install the [IDE Fix Pack for XE2](http://andy.jgknet.de/fixpack) that also fixes this bug.

Comment: Andy, one of the first things I do is install your Fix pack on any version of Delphi. I'm already uptodate with 4.6.6 and I still experience this slow down. I've also disabled the live bindings packages you mentioned for good measure. Still the minute or so drag.

Comment: In that case you may start Delphi with Delphi to debug the IDE. 1. Start Delphi and then use Run/Load Process to start "$(BDS)\bin\bds.exe". In the 2nd IDE you open you project and do the design/code switch. While the 2nd IDE is busy, you switch to the 1st IDE and press the *Pause* button. Double click on the main thread (1st thread) in the Thread-Liste and have a look at the call stack. This may help you to find the cause for the slow down.

Comment: delphicoreide160.@Pasmgr@TPascalScanner@NextToken$qqrv:

Comment: Sorry,following your suggestion, these are typical areas where the main thread seems to be spending its time... delphicoreide160.@Pasmgr@TPascalScanner@CheckDirective$qqrrpc:
delphicoreide160.@Pasmgr@TPascalScanner@NextToken$qqrv: @Codemgr@TScanner@GetSourcePos$qqrv: delphicoreide160.@Pasmgr@TPascalCodeManager@ParseClassGroup$qqro:

Comment: EMBT should hire Andy. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this after I installed the hotfix "RAD Studio XE Hotfix for RAID 280864 (QC 88928)".

page: https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41312

Comment: I also install the hotfix "Delphi XE, C++Builder XE and RAD Studio XE Hotfix for QC 90864" about corrects an IDE hang caused during a background compile operation